# Why can't Eclipse detect javacv functions beginning with cv

Tags: java, opencv

I'm learning JavaCV, and I found a really nice example online here in C++

http://aishack.in/tutorials/an-introduction-to-contours/

However, Eclips can't detect any of the functions that start with cv. like cvCreateImage(), even if the method is static. I'm at a loss for what to do here. Other Java tutorials for javacv also use these methods.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Eclipse can't detect ...". Does your project compile? If not, what's the exact compiler error message?

Comment: @jb-nizet The method cvCreateImage(null, int, int) is undefined for the type ShapeFinder

Comment: Could you point to a place where the API doc or source of ShapeFinder can be found. I haven't been able to find it. But if Eclipse tells you that the method doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: ShapeFinder is a class I created. Almost all the tutorials for JavaCV use these functions. Here's a copy of ShapeFinder http://pastie.org/5572610. I wanted to use the cv functions inside findSquare() at the bottom

Comment: There is no `cvCreateImage()` method in this class. The only methods it has are `find()` and `findSquares()`, and this last one is private. So the only method you can call on a ShapeFinder instance if `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it didn't work - you have to add some static references at the top. This is what I added if anyone else is stuck

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```